# Matching coefficients with sympy

Tags: sympy

I am attempting to work a problem from a textbook in sympy, but sympy fails to find a solution which appears valid. For interest, it is the design of a PID controller using direct synthesis with a second order plus dead time model.

The whole problem can be reduced to finding K_C, tau_I and tau_D which will make

```
K_C*(s**2*tau_D*tau_I + s*tau_I + 1)/(s*tau_I) 
= (s**2*tau_1*tau_2 + s*tau_1 + s*tau_2 + 1)/(K*s*(-phi + tau_c))
```

for given `tau_1`, `tau_2`, `K` and `phi`.

I have tried to solve this by matching coefficients:

```
import sympy

s, tau_c, tau_1, tau_2, phi, K = sympy.symbols('s, tau_c, tau_1, tau_2, phi, K')

target = (s**2*tau_1*tau_2 + s*tau_1 + s*tau_2 + 1)/(K*s*(-phi + tau_c))

K_C, tau_I, tau_D = sympy.symbols('K_C, tau_I, tau_D', real=True)
PID = K_C*(1 + 1/(tau_I*s) + tau_D*s)

eq = (target - PID).together()
eq *= sympy.denom(eq).simplify()
eq = sympy.poly(eq, s)

sympy.solve(eq.coeffs(), [K_C, tau_I, tau_D])
```

This returns an empty list. However, the textbook provides the following solution:

```
booksolution = {K_C: 1/K*(tau_1 + tau_2)/(tau_c - phi),
                tau_I: tau_1 + tau_2,a
                tau_D: tau_1*tau_2/(tau_1 + tau_2)}
```

Which appears to satisfy the equations I'm trying to solve:

```
[c.subs(booksolution).simplify() for c in eq.coeffs()]
```

returns

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

Can I massage this into a form which sympy can solve? What am I doing wong?

**Edit**: This finds the correct solution, but requires a little too much thought from my side to order the equations:

```
eqs = eq.coeffs()
solution = {}
solution[K_C] = sympy.solve(eqs[1], K_C)[0]
solution[tau_D] = sympy.solve(eqs[0], tau_D)[0].subs(solution)
solution[tau_I] = sympy.solve(eqs[2], tau_I)[0].subs(solution).simplify()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SymPy 1.0 (to be released soon) I get this answer

```
In [25]: sympy.solve(eq.coeffs(), [K_C, tau_I, tau_D])

Out[25]:
⎡                  ⎧     -(τ₁ + τ₂)         τ₁⋅τ₂               ⎫⎤
⎢{K_C: 0, τ_I: 0}, ⎨K_C: ───────────, τ_D: ───────, τ_I: τ₁ + τ₂⎬⎥
⎣                  ⎩     K⋅(φ - τ_c)       τ₁ + τ₂              ⎭⎦
```

which looks like your textbook's solution.